# Log not created, viewer cannot find it

Tags: logs, logging, configandlog

On my acceptance environment the Civicrm-log is not created. When I use Log Viewer, it cannot find it obviously. But the error message describes a specific file:

> Unable to read entries from logfile at
> /home/xxx/domains/xxx/private_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.3e4f19629d0809162da910db.log

I have checked file permissions and they seem to be okay. So the file can be created.

Two questions:

1. How can I solve the problem that the log file is not created?
2. How does log viewer know the (non-existent) log file?

Comment: When you say the permissions seem to be okay, can you be more explicit? The log file will be written by the web server user (often www-data or httpd).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case it is 'access' (DA/CustomBuild). I just ran a script to set all permissions right from a Drupal perspective. Now the log is created. So you were right that something was not correct.

Comment: Strange thing, but this problem has returned. I have set the permissions again, but to no avail.

Comment: I am now also having this error with no log files in the folder despite 775 permissions and Apache as the owner.  @webmaster-covs, were you able to able to resolve this?